# how to integrate passportjs google oauth20 in expo react native app 2023

Tags: react-native, expo, google-oauth, passport.js

so i created all api routes of google oauth20 using passportjs with the help of nodejs now i can't figure out how can i integrate the api in my expo react native app. but i tried to integrate the api in the app but it shows this error **[AxiosError: Network Error]**

the below code is passportjs google ouath using nodejs which i tried in expo react native app

```
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;

const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: true,
  })
);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  next();
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "8fuydf89y7d9f8uyd8fhdjfhdf",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID:
        "client-id",
      clientSecret: "client-sec",
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
    },
    function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
      console.log(profile);
      return done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

// Routes

const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.cookies["connect.sid"];
  if (!token) {
    return next(new Error("Not Authenticated"));
  }
  next();
};

app.get("/me", isAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  if (req.user) {
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: "successfull",
      user: req.user,
    });
  }
});

app.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);

app.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", { failureRedirect: "/login" }),
  (req, res) => {
    res.send("You are logged in");
  }
);

app.get("/logout", (req, res) => {
  req.session.destroy((err) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.clearCookie("connect.sid", {
      secure: false,
      httpOnly: false,
      sameSite: false,
    });
    res.status(200).json({
      message: "Logged Out",
    });
  });
});

app.listen(4008, () => {
  console.log("Server is running on port 4008");
});
```

and the below code is expo react native code which i implemented

i created a function called handleLogin where i used axios to call the api

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
    await axios
      .get("http://localhost:4008/auth/google", {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err", err);
      });
  };
```

here is the google button code

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={handleLogin}>
                    <View style={styles.gficon}>
                      <AntDesign name="google" size={32} color="#EA4335" />
                    </View>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
```

so what i want like when a user click the google button a prompt will open and the user can select his google acoount and after the successful login the user will be redirect to homescreen